# rTorrent watch directory not working

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rtorrent

I am having trouble getting watch directories to work in rTorrent.

I have this in my .rtorrent.rc file:

```
schedule = watch_directory,5,5,"load_start=/home/rtorrent/watch/*.torrent"
schedule = untied_directory,5,5,stop_untied=
```

There are 4 torrent files in `/home/rtorrent/watch` but none of them are showing up in rtorrent.

**Versions**
rTorrent: 0.9.2
libtorrent: 0.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torrent files were not valid.